# How to override only OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.BaseURL property in IIB?

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus

- This is part of the flow, if I rewrite the url and configure at ComputeNode(ComPrepare) the URL is overwritten, everything works fine.

[image]

- But REST Request Node(postRegister) will lose headers as part of my config in REST Request node(postRegister). So how can I rewrite the URL in ComputeNode(ComPrepare) and keep the header at the REST Request node(postRegister)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm resolved my problem. I set configuration in compute node:

```
SET InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.BaseURL = 'http://localhost:8888/thanbv';
```

And I set default compute mode is Message. Thanks for everyone :v